# Two background images separated diagonally

Tags: html, css

It's possible to have two background images separated diagonally with CSS?

I know how to make it only with one image but I couldn't do it with two images.

Here's an example:

```
|-------------|
|            /|
|           / |
|          /  |
|         /   |
|        /    |
|       /     |
|      /      |
|Img1 / Img2  |
|    /        |
|   /         |
|  /          |
| /           |
|/            |
|-------------|
```

Thank you in advance.

---

**UPDATE**

It has to be responsive, cross-browser and only with CSS (if possible).

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/whv0rtLw/) of what I'm looking (one image only)

Comment: is the aspect ratio fixed? if so then you can precompute the composite image and it will just work. if the aspect ratio varies, you'll have to settle for non-uniform scaling if want the diagonal to run through the corners. alternatively, don't use background-image, but use regular images and clip-path https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: using a clipping mask would also be effective depending on what you need to accomplish in later steps. good answer.

Comment: I've updated my question. It has to be responsive, cross-browser and only with CSS (if possible).

Answer (score 3):

Check this CSS and JS solution: https://jsfiddle.net/u7hf0y1g/
It does not generate a division between the bottom left and the upper right corner but it creates a responsive division.

HTML:

```
<div class="maincontent">
  <ul class="trapezoid">
    <li id="trap-1">
      <div class="inner cover top-right" style="background-image: url('http://www.pressedfortimelincoln.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/placeholder1-1024x768.png'); background-color: #ffffff">
      </div>
    </li>
      <li id="trap-2">
        <div class="inner cover top-right" style="background-image: url('http://www.pacinno.eu/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder-Copy.png'); background-color: #ffffff">
        </div>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
window.onresize = function () {
  var trap1 = document.getElementById('trap-1');
  var trap2 = document.getElementById('trap-2');
  var width = trap1.offsetWidth;
  var height = trap1.offsetHeight;
  var marginLeft = Math.round(Math.sin(10 / 180 * Math.PI) * height /  2 * 1.02);
  var imageWidth = marginLeft + width;
  var trap1inner = document.querySelector('#trap-1 .inner');
  var viewport = window.innerWidth;
  var newWidth = viewport - (width - (marginLeft + marginLeft));

  trap1.style.marginLeft = '-' + marginLeft + 'px';
  trap1inner.style.width = imageWidth + 'px';
  trap2.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
}
var evt = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false,window,0);
window.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.maincontent {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.trapezoid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.trapezoid li {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}
.trapezoid li .inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.inner.top-right {
  background-position: top right;
}
.inner.cover {
  background-size: cover;
 }
.inner.full-width {
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
#trap-1 {
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-10deg);
  transform: skew(-10deg);
  z-index: 3;
}
#trap-1 .inner {
  -webkit-transform: skew(10deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(10deg);
  transform: skew(10deg);
}
#trap-2 {
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Credits: detomon-monoxid, iamso.io, Luisa Low Pew

Comment: It looks great but it isn't totally diagonally. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach with a mixture of svg/css/js code, using svg patterns: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBbGjm

It's vertically and horizontally responsive (though only vert. on codepen).

It had worked for me on newer versions of safari/firefox/chrome and on IE10 and IE11, as well as on the android browser 4.1.2.

Though this approach doesn't work solely with css, svg patterns have many interesting features which might be additionally useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Element/pattern

**CODE:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 500 600" id="svg" width="500" height="600" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <defs>
            <pattern id="svgimg1" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="500" height="600">
                <image xlink:href="http://vectorpatterns.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/greencirclepattern.png" x="0" y="0" width="550" height="600"></image>
            </pattern>
            <pattern id="svgimg2" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="500" height="600">
                <image xlink:href="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/b7/d5/f1/b7d5f1e6b9b92b50f8b69498aa5073cd.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="540" height="720"></image>
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <polygon id="svgcont2" fill="url(#svgimg2)"></polygon>
        <polygon id="svgcont1" fill="url(#svgimg1)"></polygon>
    </svg>
</div>
</body>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #ddd;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 600px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641014/two-background-images-separated-diagonally
// http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBbGjm
window.onresize = function () {
    var cont = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper')[0];
    var svg = document.getElementById('svg');
    var triangle = document.getElementById('svgcont1');
    var rectangle = document.getElementById('svgcont2');
    var width = cont.offsetWidth;
    var height = cont.offsetHeight;

    svg.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 '+width+' '+height);
    svg.setAttribute('width', width);
    svg.setAttribute('height', height);
    triangle.setAttribute('points', '0,0 0,'+height+' '+width+',0');
    rectangle.setAttribute('points', '0,0 0,'+height+' '+width+','+height+' '+width+',0');
}
var evt = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false,window,0);
window.dispatchEvent(evt);
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `transform: skewX(-55.98deg);` https://jsfiddle.net/pkwytxz2/

```
<div class='pageOption'>
  <a href='#' class='option' data-inf='photo'>
    <img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2009-28-b-large_web.jpg'>
  </a>
  <a href='#' class='option' data-inf='cinema'>
    <img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2013-06-a-large_web.jpg'>
  </a>
</div>
```

css

```
    body { background: gainsboro; }
.pageOption {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 40em; height: 27em;
}
.option, .option img { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.option {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;  
  /* arctan(27 / 40) = 34.01935deg 
   * need to skew by 90deg - 34.01935deg = 55.98065deg
  */
  transform: skewX(-55.98deg);
}
.option:first-child {
  left: -.25em;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}
.option:last-child {
  right: -.25em;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
.option img { opacity: .75; transition: .5s; }
.option img:hover { opacity: 1; }
.option img, .option:after {
  transform: skewX(55.98deg);
  transform-origin: inherit;
}
.option:after {
  position: absolute;
  margin: .5em 1.65em;
  color: white;
  font: 500 1.25em Courier;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  content: attr(data-inf);
}
.option:first-child:after { top: 0; left: 0; }
.option:last-child:after { right: 0; bottom: 0; }
```

Comment: Very nice but it's not responsive. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `clip-path` to do this:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
}

.image-angled {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-angled--top {
  background: url(https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2551/3848453164_a125d45959_b.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 0);
}

.image-angled--bottom {
  background: url(http://2ndavenuescooters.com/wp-content/uploads/0067.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-angled image-angled--top"></div>
  <div class="image-angled image-angled--bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost perfect but it doesn't work on Firefox (not even tested on IE). Thank you anyway.